# Using if-condition in pandas to fill na values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, mapping

I have some columns in df where one of the columns has a missing value. I need to fill them but only when the ColumnY has a False value.

Here is how df looks

```
A                 B                    C
Value             4                    True
v3                9                    True
v9                                     False
v0                4                    False
```

I have a dictionary which I am using to map the values in column B ...

```
di_map = {'V3' : 'A',  'V9' : 'X', 'V0' : 'Z'  }



df['B'] =  df['A'].map(di_map)
```

Here is how output should look

```
A                 B                    C
Value             4                    True
v3                9                    True
v9                X                    False
v0                Z                    False
```

Comment: Why is the value 4 replaced?

Comment: because i need to map all the values where C column is false

Comment: @s_khan92, can you include values of ``di_map`` in the question.

Comment: Ok i added :) @sushanth

Comment: @s_khan92 try, ``df.loc[~df['C'], 'B'] = df.loc[~df['C'], 'A'].str.upper().map(di_map)``

Comment: @sushanth Thanks... Thats what i wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`Series.where()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

- In rows where `df.C` is `True`, keep the original `df.B` value
- In rows where `df.C` is `False`, use `df.A.str.upper().map(di_map)`

```py
df['B'] = df.B.where(df.C, df.A.str.upper().map(di_map))

#        A    B      C
# 0  Value  4.0   True
# 1     v3  9.0   True
# 2     v9    X  False
# 3     v0    Z  False
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m a bit confused with your question as I don´t see any columnY in your df.

But based on your target output, you can try this one:

```
df["B"].iloc(df["C"]==False) = "New_Val"
```

or

```
df["B"].loc(df["C"]==False) = "New_Val"
```

depends on your python version.